# Is there a way to listen to event when a cookie is changed in a Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I am trying to build a firefox extension which listens to events when a cookie is changed by any domain from any page and handle it accordingly. Is there an easy way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Have a look at the code of the FireCookie extension: http://code.google.com/p/firecookie/source/browse/trunk/

Answer (score 7):

You can listen to the [cookie-changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsICookieService) topic with the [observer service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIObserverService).

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/5RsTm/4/

try changing the cookie, it will pop up an alert.

Comment: Yes but then you're adding an endless 100 ms timer to your page, and also this could add some serious race conditions onto your page. I would be wary to use this... but it'll work...

Comment: Yes, the loop is bad, so hacky.

Comment: Yes it was a dirty hack. Realising looking back.