# Identity cookie expiry

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

How would I redirect to login page AUTOMATICALLY, if my Identity cookie has expired at "ExpireTimeSpan" value? I do understand there is an event "OnRedirectToLogin" but that doesn't get triggered unless a request comes through. Is there a way, I can redirect to login right after the cookie has expired rather than keep sending requests to verify it has timed out?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand, what you want is the server to reach out to the client, but standard client/server HTTP works the other way around. The client is supposed to send requests to the server, and at some point to get redirected if its authentication cookie has expired, but if the cookie expires and the client never ask the server for anything more ever, then it doesn't have to be told anything has expired. Communication the other way around, where servers notify clients can be achieved by several means but is to be reserved for very particular needs. Are you sure you need that?

Comment: I totally understand what you trying to say here. But in my application, when the identity cookie expires, the subsequent request would redirect to login page and the user needs to login to access his page. So, as the user is unaware that his cookie has expired and tries to access his page, redirecting back to login page might be little annoying - rather I want to redirect to login page after cookie expiry or after some idle time and notify him, I signed you out cz you were idle for certain time.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean. There are two different things you can set here: 1. the duration of the session that will be encrypted and handled only on the server 2. the expires /max age of the cookie returned to the brower. Maybe you could set that expires / max age to something similar to the session validy, and then react, purely client side, on the expiring of the cookie?

Comment: You could create a cookie when login on the server with a proper max age and listen to cookie changing client side with a piece of javascript like that: http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/5RsTm/4/ (credit to people from the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132561/is-there-a-way-to-listen-to-event-when-a-cookie-is-changed-in-a-firefox-extensio) That would avoid back and forth between the client and the server.